# Current time timestamp in org-capture-templates

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, time-date, org-capture

In org-mode org-capture templates, what is the way to insert current time timestamp?

I've tried `%U` like so:

```
(setq
 org-capture-templates
 (quote
  (
     ("k" "Capture an item and schedule it for tomorrow" entry
      (file+headline "today.org" "_tomorrow")
      "* TODO %^{Task Title} %^G
SCHEDULED: %t
Added: %U @ %a" :immediate-finish t))))
```

but the `%U` shortcode always produces 00:00 time and the date is the same as the agenda view date at which the point is located at the time the `org-capture` is invoked.

By the way, I'd also like some suggestions on how to produce a "tomorrow" timestamp in the template, but that is probably a topic for another question.

Comment: What Emacs and Org versions do you have?  Your code works for me as expected.

Comment: Emacs 25.0.50.1, Org-mode version 8.2.10. Did you invoke `org-capture` from agenda view?

Comment: I invoked `org-capture` from the agenda view and your code worked as expected: `%U` had been replaced by inactive time stamp with current date and time.

Comment: OK, `%U` worked for me too, but only in the TODO agenda view. In the week or day agenda views the time gets set to `00:00` and the date gets copied from the selected agenda date, not the current time. Is that a bug or a feature?

Comment: or maybe there is some variable responsible for this behavior?

Comment: I tried to invoke `org-capture` but indeed you invoked `org-agenda-capture`. As @erikstokes metioned it is a bug - I have `00:00` too.

Answer (score 3):

According the help for `org-agenda-capture` (bound to `k` in agenda views)

> Call ‘org-capture’ with the date at point.
>   With a ‘C-1’ prefix, use the HH:MM value at point (if any) or the
>   current HH:MM time.

It works correctly *if* you position the cursor on a line that has a time.  Otherwise the time seems to always get set to "00:00".  The function responsible for getting the time is `org-get-cursor-date`.  This function claims:

> Return the date at cursor in as a time.
>   This works in the calendar and in the agenda, anywhere else it just
>   returns the current time.
>   If WITH-TIME is non-nil, returns the time of the event at point (in
>   the agenda) or the current time of the day.

Everywhere *except* in on a line in an agenda view that doesn't have time, the function behaves as advertised.  But if it doesn't find some kind of a timestamp, it defaults the current day at midnight.  The relevent piece of code is

```
(setq date (calendar-gregorian-from-absolute day)
        defd (encode-time 0 (or mod 0) (or hod 0)
                  (nth 1 date) (nth 0 date) (nth 2 date)))
```

`mod` and `hod` are the minute and hour, but aren't getting set and thus default to 0.

This seems to contradict the stated intent of the function and is likely a bug rather than a feature.

Comment: Maybe it is called `org-agenda-capture` not `org-capture-agenda`?

Comment: @artscan Yep.  Edited.